# Selective deployment for iPad (exclude iPad 1, 2, 3) - Best practices

Tags: ios, ipad, deployment

Is it possible to restrict an iPad application from running on iPad 1, 2 and 3? We have a game that requires iPad 4 or higher hardware and will not work with iPad 1 2 or 3, and we don't want to get bad reviews from people with iPad 3 trying to use our game.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to worry about the iPad 1 unless you needlessly chose to support iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

YES, you can restrict your project to specific iOS devices, but not by selecting them device-by-device. Instead, you need to specify in XCode that your project requires certain hardware features that may or may not be present on the device(s) you want to build to.

Here are some relevant resources:
A specific application example of hardware restriction: http://www.appsbynight.com/2012/02/20/lock-users-from-running-an-app-on-older-ios-devices/

Restrict based on armv6 or armv7 https://www.innerfence.com/howto/apple-ios-devices-dates-versions-instruction-sets

Restrict based on OpenGL ES 2.0 or 3.0
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

List of ways to restrict hardware in your application:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3